# Drop down list that allows blank or null to be selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ado.net

My dropdown list is bound to a database, I want it to allow the selection of nulls. Therefore, when it is selected nothing goes into the table. Right now, it works if I were to set the value to an integer, but I don't want it to work this way. How can I do this programmatically in the easiest way possible in ASP.NET?

I was able to insert the blank into the drop down however when selected it's not inserting the null value into the table when I click my insert button. I keep getting error messages either saying error converting `Nvarchar` to `int` or an FK constraint message I believe which is due to the database not allowing things to be inserted that aren't in that table in the database.

Here is the code I used to create the blank:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDlContract" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ContractName" DataValueField="ContractID" Width="200px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <Items>
        <asp:ListItem Text="" value =""></asp:ListItem>
    </Items>
```

I tried:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDlContract" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ContractName" DataValueField="ContractID" Width="200px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
    <Items>
        <asp:ListItem Text="" value =""></asp:ListItem>
    </Items>
```

I was expecting it to allow me to insert a `null` value.

Here is the insertion code:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Databinder();
}

protected void BtnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string GPOEmailID = TxtGPO.Text;
    string LastName = TxtLname.Text;
    string FirstName = TxtFname.Text;
    string WorkPhone = TxtWork.Text;
    string ContractID = DDlContract.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string JobSeriesID = DDlJob.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string PositionID = DDlPosition.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string PersonalPhone = TxtPersonal.Text;
    string SupervisorGPOEmailID = DDlSupervisor.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string EmpCatID = DDlCat.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string EmpStatusID = DDlStatus.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string EmployeeRoleID = DDlRole.SelectedValue.ToString();

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.spNewEmployeeList ", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GPOEmailID ", GPOEmailID);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName ", LastName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName ", FirstName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkPhone ", WorkPhone);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractID ", ContractID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobSeriesID ", JobSeriesID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PositionID  ", PositionID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalPhone ", PersonalPhone);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupervisorGPOEmailID ", SupervisorGPOEmailID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpCatID ", EmpCatID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpStatusID ", EmpStatusID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeRoleID ", EmployeeRoleID);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    LoadRecord();
}
```

```
For my Update button code how would I go about this same process, here is the code. I am trying to allow nulls values for the following Data center ID, Environment ID, Designation ID, and Computer status ID:

 protected void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string ComputerID = DDlUpdate.SelectedValue.ToString();
     int CPUType =  Convert.ToInt32(DDlType.SelectedValue);
     string VIP_ID = DDlVIP.SelectedValue.ToString();
     string IPAddress = TxtIpaddress.Text;
     string PhysicalIDAddress = TxtPhysical.Text;
     string OS = TxtOS.Text;
     string Patchgroup = TxtPatchGroup.Text;
     string Location = TxtLocation.Text;
     string MacAddress = TxtMac.Text;
     string ComputerURL = TxtUrl.Text;
     string ComputerName = TxtName.Text;
     string DataCenterID = DDlDatacenter.SelectedValue.ToString();
     string EnvironmentID = DDlEnvironment.SelectedValue.ToString();
     string DesignationID = DDlDesignationID.SelectedValue.ToString();
     string ComputerStatusID = DDlStatus.SelectedValue.ToString();
     
     int Valid;
     if (IsValid.Checked == true)
     {
         Valid = 1;
     }
     else
     {
         Valid = 0;
     }

     con.Open();
     SqlCommand co = new SqlCommand("exec spModifyComputersList '" + ComputerID + "','" + VIP_ID + "','" +  CPUType + "','" + PhysicalIDAddress + "','" + IPAddress + "','" + OS + "','" + Patchgroup + "','" + Location + "','" + MacAddress + "','" + ComputerURL + "','" + ComputerName + "','" + DataCenterID + "','" + EnvironmentID + "','" + DesignationID + "','" + ComputerStatusID + "','" +  + Valid + "'", con);
     co.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Sucessfully Updated.');", true);
     Label1.Text = "Record has been Updated";
     GridView1.DataBind();
     DDlUpdate.DataBind();
     LoadRecord();
```

Comment: The trouble is not in your dropdown list. The trouble is in how you are inserting it into the table. A dropdown list item default value is not `NULL` rather is is `empty string` or `""`. As such, you need to handle the empty string and convert it to a `dbnull.value` before inserting into your table. Please post the code related to inserting the value from the dropdown for further assistance.

Comment: Just posted check above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the value which is `string` type (`NVARCHAR` type in SQL) to the stored procedure for `@ContractID` and the SQL parameter expects the value should be the `INT` type.

Thus, you need to handle with the scenario:

1. When the `ContractID` is null/empty string, you need to pass the value as `DBNull.Value`.
2. When the `ContractID` has value, you need to cast it into an integer.

```cs
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractID ", String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContractID)
    ? (object)DBNull.Value
    : Convert.ToInt32(ContractID));
```

In this community, we recommend **providing the parameter with value and type (length)** instead of just providing the value via `AddWithValue()`. You may read the article: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

```cs
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContractID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContractID)
    ? (object)DBNull.Value
    : Convert.ToInt32(ContractID);
```

Also, do take note that your stored procedure should be modified with the `ContractID` parameter to allow null. As it is nullable and optional, the parameter needs to be placed at the end (**mandatory/not nullable parameter(s) comes first**).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spNewEmployeeList
  -- Other Parameters,
  ContractID INT = NULL
```

Comment: To add to the above, when you are building out your lists of parameters, you should be doing so along side the ddl for the table you are operating against. Your parameters should ALL match the type associated with the column they modify. I'll second that AddWithValue is terrible. Declaring your params as Yong Shun has indicated is an immediate improvement to your code quality.

Comment: how do I do the same thing for my update button code, I added it above.

Comment: Hi @Sleep3000, it would be great if you have a new question, post it as a new question post instead of updating the original question. As the answer was proposed to solve your original question. Thanks.

Comment: For your updation code, you should use the parameterized query but not string concatenation as what you have did for `dbo.spNewEmployeeList`.